# What should I do if I found a popular answer is wrong?

Tags: discussion

Please see my question and answer here.

[Difference between variance and standard deviation: Is this popular answer wrong?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267534/difference-between-variance-and-standard-deviation-is-this-popular-answer-wrong)

What should I do? correct the code and statements? It needs many corrections, even include the code of calculating the likelihood.

Comment: As I commented there, I strongly object to describing the situation as "the answer is wrong". The answer is fine, pedagogical, and helpful. It's not "wrong". It contains some mistakes/inconsistencies in the code/text, that can be relatively easily fixed without affecting the logic of the answer. If the author does not fix these mistakes following your comment there, then maybe you could do it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a general principle, the first thing to do is consider the possibility that you're mistaken. If there's already comments there, check to see what the discussion says and what may already have been done about it

Then:

- Try commenting about the issue first; perhaps the poster can be induced to fix it themselves.
- Consider also posting a correct answer where you refer to the mistaken one.

Actually correcting someone else's answer would normally be limited to minor fixes (downvotes and or comments are the usual way to indicate disagreement), but I can see the increased desire to deal with it when there's a popular but potentially misleading answer that novices might accept uncritically.

Comment: I would add that fixing someone else's "popular but [potentially] misleading answer" is sometimes warranted when its author is not active on CV anymore.

Comment: I agree with @amoeba there - when, as in this case, we're not talking about changing the gist of the answer, but rectifying small but nevertheless substantive mistakes. Probably best to get some consensus among other users that the mistakes are indeed mistakes first.